# Referencing VS 2012 to SQL Server 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2005, integration

I have some SQL CLR and stored procedures which I created on a SQL Server 2005 database using Visual Studio 2012 but I need to have a SQL Server 2005 database associated rather than the default SQL Server 2012.

How can I create a 2005 database from VS 2012? I tried changing the target DB version to SQL Server 2005 - but it does not work.

Comment: You will need to install some version of SQL Server 2005 - the free Express edition can do as long as your DB size is below 4 GB

Comment: @marc_s i am not using an express version

Comment: I just said you need to install a SQL Server **2005** version - if you do have a license for a Standard or Enterprise version - go ahead and use that. But you need SQL Server **2005** - you cannot create a database that will be usable for SQL Server 2005 on a later version

Comment: @marc_s yes I have a SQL server 2005 installed, but I am still not able to use it with VS 2012. I have changed the target DB to 2005, but it still associates only 2012 DBs .